# Fetch react sin Json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

tengo un proyecto que hice con jquery, usaba ajax para llamar al servidor pasandole parametros por POST.

El fetch lo he visto siempre pero pasandole los parametros en formato Json.  Me gustaría hacerlo pasando los parametros sin que sea Json. Lo estoy intentando asi...

```
 const datos = {
        username: username,
        password: password
  }
    fetch('https://prs/react/login.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    body: datos
              }) 

                .then(function(datos) {
                  console.log('datos =', datos);
                  return datos;
              })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar `JSON.stringify` para enviar los parámetros.

```
const datos = {
  username: username,
  password: password
};
fetch("https://prs/react/login.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(datos)
}).then(function(datos) {
  console.log("datos =", datos);
  return datos;
});
```

Más info de cómo usar `fetch` [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch).